# mocha + webstorm - error message broken

Tags: windows, node.js, phpstorm, mocha.js

I try to use mocha with webstorm test runner on win 7.

I have these config params:

- path to node:

  ```
  C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe
  ```

  working directory:

  ```
  D:\creation\software developer\projects\dev\document root\
  ```

  path to node app js file:

  ```
  C:\Users\inf3rno\node_modules\mocha\bin\_mocha
  ```

  application parameters:

  ```
  test
  ```

I got the following error message in webstorm console

```
✖ 1 of 1 test failed:
```

but nothing about which test failed. :S

How to fix it?

(in git bash I got a detailed error message, so mocha is installed well)

Tried with different reporters, but none of them seems working. The problem is with the Error object I think. Everything else is displayed well.

Wrote a custom reporter and found that it's fully random whether the stack shows up on the webstorm console, or not. The best choice was to print it with process.stderr.write, with console.log or process.stdout.write appears nothing. I don't know why is that. Maybe it's some type of timeout, but I set the timeout to 9999999. :S :S :S Hmm maybe the webstorm runner has a timeout, and it depends on that, not on the mocha timeout settings...

Tested with this reporter:

```
exports = module.exports = WebStorm;

/**
 * Initialize a new `WebStorm` test reporter.
 *
 * @param {Runner} runner
 * @api public
 */

 //decribe -> suite
 //it -> test

function WebStorm(runner) {
  var buffer = [];
  var suites = [];
  var fails = [];

  runner.on("suite", function(suite){
     suites.push(suite.title || "''");
  });

  runner.on("suite end", function(suite){
     if (fails.length > 0)
         buffer.push("describe "+suites.join(".")+"\n"+fails.join("\n"));
     fails = [];
     suites.pop();
  });

  runner.on("fail", function(test, err){
      fails.push("  it fail "+test.fullTitle() + err.message);
  });

  runner.on("end", function (){
      process.stderr.write(buffer.length+"\n");
      //process.stderr.write(buffer.join("\n"));
  });
}
```

I found it does not really matter how long the output text is, just how long you have to wait before displaying it. So I still think it's a timeout problem, and not an stdout bug. The webstorm console returns: "Process finished with exit code 59" which means "An unexpected network error occured."

Changed to jasmine-node, it's working.

## Edit:

I changed to jasmine2, it had the same issue on windows. The simplest workaround is deferring `process.exit` for example with 1ms. So it cannot exit before the end of the `stdout.write`. (Manually flushing the stdout and calling exit only after that is probably a working solution as well.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's caused by a [known Windows specific node issue](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/1669), also [logged in JetBrains issue tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-12344).

Comment: Nice, thanks! Any idea why is it working well in git bash, and why not in webstorm console?

Comment: Haha I know it, git bash is an emulated linux, and this is a windows issue. :P

Comment: I got this in webstorm console: "Process finished with exit code 59", which means: "59 An unexpected network error occurred."

Comment: According to the link, it will be fixed in  Node.js v0.11.12. Until that the only thing you can do is sending the report only once, so it might arrive.

Comment: **I had it working on Windows** in Webstorm as well however now it's not working any more, that why I'm here. Now I think it happens since I changed node executable path, so it might work on latest versions. Note that this has no link with cygwin/git bash: I have it working perfectly from windows cmd.

Comment: I just confirm: no more error output issue with `node.exe` 0.12.2 x64

Answer (score 5):

While the greater powers are [debating on the hows and the whys to fix this](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/3584), lesser mortals can resort to this workaround:

- Create a file called testRunner.js (or whatever)
- add the following lines of code to it
- modify the list of test files per your project
- in webstorm, run the `testRunner.js` to run your tests

**testRunner.js**

```
var testFiles=["test/_helper.js","test/tests.js","test/tests.coffee"];

var Mocha = require('mocha');

var mocha = new Mocha;

mocha.reporter('spec').ui('bdd');

for (var i =0;i<testFiles.length;i++){
 mocha.addFile(testFiles[i]);
}

var runner = mocha.run(function(){
                console.log('finished');

});
```

Courtesy: http://wuntusk.blogspot.com/2012/06/using-webstorm-or-phpstorm-and-mocha.html

Comment: @RefaelAckermann: Nice one! I guess it can be tweaked to run one file at a time too coz often times, I don't want to wait for other tests to finish while debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Even after implementing Mrchief's answer, I am still getting scrambled reports in the output. I ended up running tests in the terminal window. As a reference;

Make sure mocha is installed globally.

> ```
> npm install -g mocha
> ```

Open the terminal window (Alt-Minus) and change to the directory where your test scripts are

Run mocha

> mocha -R spec *.js