# Running jasmine tests in Webstorm stops in trace with exit code 0

Tags: node.js, jasmine, gruntjs, webstorm

I run jasmine tests in my node.js application via grunt. I've added `grunt test` to Webstorm's run configurations.

In "Run/Debug Configurations" the "Grunt Test" has following properties specified: node interpreter (`node.exe` in Program Files), working directory (project location), JavaScript file (grunt binary), and application parameters (`test` - grunt task name).

The configuration works correctly but stops without printing full jasmine output. Sometimes before printing any output, most often after some part of jasmine log, but before test summary or error details. Always the last line of output is

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

When I take the Webstorm command and run it manually in console it works fine and always prints full output:

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\...\node_modules\grunt-cli\bin\grunt test
```

My tests includes asynchronous cases, so it takes about 20 seconds to run them all.
I noticed that each attempt to run tests via Webstorm prints a bit longer output. First attempt ends without any but after ten further I got full output with test summary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the case described in question we can run jasmine tests directly by jasmine-node command (skipping grunt).

We have to set up new "Run/Debug Configuration" based on "Node.js" pre-conf.

- Node interpreter (as usual):

  ```
  C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
  ```
- Working directory: project root,
- JavaScript file:

  ```
  node_modules\grunt-jasmine-node\node_modules\jasmine-node\lib\jasmine-node\cli.js
  ```

  This is for my case (using grunt-jasmine-node). We can also provide path to `cli.js` of jasmine-node installed globally.
- Application variables:

  ```
  --verbose src/test/js
  ```

  Of course the last one is a path to directory of tests in my project. Here we can specify list of files or use other [jasmine-node](https://npmjs.org/package/jasmine-node) commands and parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Known issue, please see http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-1926 and discussion on stackoverflow ([mocha + webstorm - error message broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151940/mocha-webstorm-error-message-broken/19009547#19009547))

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've spent a lot of time searching any workaround.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that `process.exit()` does not wait the `stdout`. You should defer the exit call with one tick, that's all.