# Web Storm 7.0.3 doesn't show log for mocha

Tags: mocha.js, webstorm

I use web-storm 7.0.3 and integrated mocha tests.
I have wired problem, console.log() shows only first line (in web-storm output window), all consequent logs are not displayed.
When I run mocha from console, I could see all log info as expected.
What could be problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely this is the known Node issue: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/1669
See also [mocha + webstorm - error message broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151940/mocha-webstorm-error-message-broken)

Answer (score 0):

## this could possible work  (for sync tests)

```
after (next) ->
  #give chance to log output
  setTimeout next, 200
```